# how to get base address of string in printf? what is reason for this o/p?

Tags: c, printf

the following is code...i want to know how actually it works i.e why the output is so?

```
{
   printf(5 + "GeeksQuiz");
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT : Quiz

Comment: I urge you to figure this out for yourself, even if you have to learn about C pointer arithmetic in the process. You're missing out on a lot of fun by posting this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @PaulKeister okay...next time i will try figure things myself before posting on stackoverflow..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf(5 + "GeeksQuiz");
    return 0;
}
```

In order to understand how this works, you begin with `man 3 printf`. Looking at the relevant parts you find:

```
The  functions  in  the printf() family produce output according to a format 
as described below. ...

The format string is a character string, beginning and ending in its initial 
shift state, if any. ...

Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %, and ends with
a conversion specifier.
```

Ok, let's look a little closer at what we have:

```
printf(5 + "GeeksQuiz");
```

The **format** string -- that must be `"GeeksQuiz"`; **beginning** and ending in its **initial shift state** -- that must be the **5**; where each **conversion specification** is introduced by the character `%`, and ends with  a  `conversion specifier` -- I don't see anything introduce with a `%` so there must be no conversion specification in the string. ...

So it appears we have `printf` with a **format string** of `"GeeksQuiz"` and an **initial shift state** of `5`. How does that work out?

```
    GeeksQuiz
    ---------
    012345678  --  9 characters, character indexes 0-8
    ---------
--> 12345      --  shift state of 5, that's indexes 0-4
    -----Quiz  --  leaves us with Quiz
```

So from making **1** stop at `man 3 printf` we have learned exactly what `printf(5 + "GeeksQuiz");` is and why it does what it does.

Comment: Your are welcome. I was glad to have those smarter than I was help me along when I had questions. (still am)

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is attributed to pointer arithmetic. `"GeeksQuiz"` is of type `char[10]` (i.e., 9 characters plus the `\0` null character at the end), expression `5 + "GeeksQuiz"` returns a pointer to the sixth element of "GeeksQuiz" (i.e., `&(char[5])`). Thus, `printf` prints `"Quiz"`.

Comment: C string literals are not `const`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, obviously confused with C++, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the content inside printf is interpreted at compile time then only it is fetched to the printf statement.

Here the string "GeeksQuiz" decays to a pointer to its first element or is interpreted as a pointer to a string. If it was a simple statement like

```
    printf("GeeksQuiz");
```

Compiler would return the address of the first element in the string that is "G" and printf will print it until \0 is encountered.

But in the above case

```
    printf(5 + "GeeksQuiz");   OR
    printf("GeeksQuiz" + 5);
```

Binary addition of the address of "G" and 5 will be performed and the new address generated would be returned to the printf.

Here is how the memory looks like:

```
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9      
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | G | e | e | k | s | Q | u | i | z | 0 |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Hence you can say that, printf will print the string from the 5th character in the string starting from 0 i.e. "Q",

or it skips the 5 characters and prints the given string.

Hence the output, "Quiz".

Answer (score 0):

The string literal `"GeeksQuiz"` is of type `char[]`:

> "In C, string literals are of type char[], ..." [[string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)]

However, this string literal *lvalue* is implicitly converted to a *prvalue* of type `pointer to char`:

> "A lvalue or rvalue of type "array of N T" or "array of unknown bound of T" can be implicitly converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to T". The resulting pointer refers to the first element of the array." [[Implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)]

The rest should be self-explanatory, and I'll quote *40two*'s response to have a complete answer:

> The behaviour is attributed to pointer arithmetic. "GeeksQuiz" is of type char[10] (i.e., 9 characters plus the \0 null character at the end), expression 5 + "GeeksQuiz" returns a pointer to the sixth element of "GeeksQuiz" (i.e., &(char[5])). Thus, printf prints "Quiz". [[40two's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25215592/1345237)]